# .ui-layout-north background color

Tags: css, jsf-2

I am using primefaces 4.3 and   in my main ui.

I want to change the background color in the north unit to red
For some reason its color only the top 80% of the unit

```
.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {  
   background-color: red ;
   font-size:90% !important;
 }
```

How can I change it to all the north unit

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Style the CONTENTS of the list (the A tag with `display:block`), not the container.

Also, if you're using `!important`, to probably need to [read this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) on CSS Specificity.

Comment: what do you mean "CONTENTS of the list" ? any example ?